How can I make text look like a digital message board with geometry nodes?
Here is what I am aiming for:

Here is what I currently have:

As you can see i've tried using a basic distribute points of faces node setup to turn my text into “pixels” but i don’t know how to make it follow a sort of grid like distrbution

Hello and welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the post. It should read like a question, be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the problem so that anyone searching for similar issues is likely to find this. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "this", "help with", "issue" or "question about", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on it. See What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"

(Using Blender 3.6.12)
The proposed approach assumes that the text is in the (X,Y) plane. It builds an uniform grid, then it selects only faces from this grid that are overlapping the text, to instance cubes.

1. The upper part of the graph is generating a square Grid centred on the text.
2. The lower part of the graph is based on a Raycast node to select only the faces of the grid that are "hitting" the mesh of the text.
NB: To model a full digital LED message board, it might be more convenient to create a stand-alone object for the grid, then to input it to the GeometryNodes modifier attached to the text.
Resources: 

Thank you so much!

Oh yeah my bad, I was wondering where I could accept the answer
